# T-SQL Conditional Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there difference in performance when querying someting like this?

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Name=Name
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
```

I will use it in conditional select all

```
SELECT * FROM Customer 
WHERE Name = CASE WHEN @QueryAll='true' THEN Name ELSE @SearchValue END
```

If there's no performance issue in Query 1 and 2, I think it is a short code for this one:

```
IF @QueryAll='true'
    SELECT * FROM Customer
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Name=@SearchValue
```

Comment: Note: if `Name` is nullable, the 3rd query will not return the rows where `Name` is null. Also, read sql in the wild's [catch-all queries article.](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or later, then use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` and write the query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer 
WHERE
    (Name = @SearchValue OR @QueryAll='true')
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

I usually pass `NULL` for `@SearchValue` to indicate that this parameter should be ignored, rather than using separate parameter `@QueryAll`. In this convention the query becomes this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer 
WHERE
    (Name = @SearchValue OR @SearchValue IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

**Edit**

For details see the link above. In short, `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` instructs SQL Server to recompile execution plan of the query every time it is run and SQL Server will **not** cache the generated plan. Recompilation also means that values of any variables are effectively inlined into the query and optimizer knows them.

So, if `@SearchValue` is `NULL`, optimizer is smart enough to generate the plan as if the query was this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer
```

If `@SearchValue` has a non-NULL value 'abc', optimizer is smart enough to generate the plan as if the query was this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer 
WHERE (Name = 'abc')
```

The obvious drawback of `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` is added overhead for recompilation (usually around few hundred milliseconds), which can be significant if you run the query very often.

Comment: Hi  @Vladimir Baranov, What would be the answer to my first question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the question. Query1 and Query2 may produce different result, if Name can be `NULL`, so it performance is out of the question. Query3 may be unexpectedly slower than Query4, if you don't use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. Actually, Query3 may also produce different result to Query4, if Name can be `NULL`. So, it is better not to use this style (`WHERE Name=Name`).

Comment: Hi @Vladimir Baranov ,I'll go with your 2nd query with OPTION (RECOMPILE). I use sql2008r2. Can you summarize what is the use of OPTION(RECOMPILE)? Thanks!

Comment: @janmvtrinidad, I added some explanations to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The query 2 would be faster with an index on name column, and you should specify just the fields you'll need, not all of them.

For some guidance in optional parameter queries, take a look here: [Sometimes the Simplest Solution Isn't the Best Solution (The Optional Parameter Problem)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2009/05/03/sometimes-the-simplest-solution-isn-t-the-best-solution-the-all-in-one-search-query.aspx)

Comment: I only put `*` to shorten the code, by the way, thanks for the link!